# how to capture image and video using same surfaceView

Tags: android, camera

- i have created custom camera app,
- for now its captures image and displayed in imageView.
- what i want is video capturing. how can i
- how achieve with this same surfaceView
- when swipe from left or right
- please help me

**Code**

**PreviewDemo.java**

```
package com.example.newcam;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.AutoFocusCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.media.ExifInterface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
public class PreviewDemo extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    Camera camera;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    boolean previewing = false;;
    private String imageFilePath;
    private Button buttonStartCameraPreview, buttonStopCameraPreview;
    private ImageView showImageView;
    private List<Camera.Size> mSupportedPreviewSizes;
    private Camera.Size mPreviewSize;
    static final int REQUEST_VIDEO_CAPTURE = 1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.preview);

        buttonStartCameraPreview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        // buttonStopCameraPreview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        showImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        buttonStartCameraPreview
                .setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
                    }
                });
        showImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent openImageInGallery = new Intent();
                openImageInGallery.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                openImageInGallery.setDataAndType(
                        Uri.parse("file://" + imageFilePath), "image/*");
                startActivity(openImageInGallery);
            }
        });
        surfaceView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAutoFocus(boolean focus_flag, Camera cam) {

                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                File miDirs = new File(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myphotos");
                if (!miDirs.exists())
                    miDirs.mkdirs();

                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                String new_Date = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-"
                        + ((c.get(Calendar.MONTH)) + 1) + "-"
                        + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR)
                        + "-" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + "-"
                        + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

                imageFilePath = String.format(
                        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/myphotos"
                                + "/%s.jpg", "DICM_" + new_Date);

                Uri selectedImage = Uri.parse(imageFilePath);
                File file = new File(imageFilePath);
                String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
                Bitmap bitmap = null;

                outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();

                if (path != null) {
                    if (path.startsWith("content")) {
                        bitmap = decodeStrem(file, selectedImage,
                                PreviewDemo.this);
                    } else {
                        bitmap = decodeFile(file, 10);
                    }
                }
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    showImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Picture Captured Successfully:",
                    // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    camera.startPreview();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(PreviewDemo.this,
                            "Failed to Capture the picture. kindly Try Again:",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
        }

    };

    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w,
            int h) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;
            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeFile(File f, int sampling) {
        try {
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                    new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath()), null, o2);

            o2.inSampleSize = sampling;
            o2.inTempStorage = new byte[48 * 1024];

            o2.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(
                    new FileInputStream(f.getAbsolutePath()), null, o2);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            bitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, f.getAbsolutePath());
            return bitmap;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap bmp, String imageUrl) {
        if (bmp != null) {
            ExifInterface ei;
            int orientation = 0;
            try {
                ei = new ExifInterface(imageUrl);
                orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                        ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int bmpWidth = bmp.getWidth();
            int bmpHeight = bmp.getHeight();
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED:
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.postRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.postRotate(180);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                matrix.postRotate(270);
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmpWidth,
                    bmpHeight, matrix, true);
            return resizedBitmap;
        } else {
            return bmp;
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeStrem(File fil, Uri selectedImage,
            Context mContext) {

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(mContext.getContentResolver()
                    .openInputStream(selectedImage));

            final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = getThumbSize(bitmap);

            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, THUMBNAIL_SIZE,
                    THUMBNAIL_SIZE, false);

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos
                    .toByteArray()));

            return bitmap = rotateImage(bitmap, fil.getAbsolutePath());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    public static int getThumbSize(Bitmap bitmap) {

        int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 2000;
        if (bitmap.getWidth() < 300) {
            THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 250;
        } else if (bitmap.getWidth() < 600) {
            THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 500;
        } else if (bitmap.getWidth() < 1000) {
            THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 750;
        } else if (bitmap.getWidth() < 2000) {
            THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 1500;
        } else if (bitmap.getWidth() < 4000) {
            THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 2000;
        } else if (bitmap.getWidth() > 4000) {
            THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 2000;
        }
        return THUMBNAIL_SIZE;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
            if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                parameters.setPreviewSize(580, 960);
                parameters.setRotation(90);
            } else {
                parameters.set("orientation", "landscape");
                camera.setDisplayOrientation(0);
                parameters.setRotation(0);
            }

            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // left blank for now
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int camcount = 0;
        try {

            camera = Camera.open();
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.startPreview();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
        camera = null;
    }

}
```

**layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <android.view.SurfaceView
      android:id="@+id/surface"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_white" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/video"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_white_video" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```